# jQuery deffered resolve multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();

$(document).on('click', '#Signup', function() {
    email_check('Signup');
    mobile_check('Signup');
    dfd.done(function(){
        alert("Hello World!")
    })
})

function email_check(Signup){
    dfd.resolve();
}

function mobile_check(Signup){
    dfd.resolve();
}
```

Hi everyone, I want that when deferred object resolve in both function  email_check and mobile_check. Then after executing the alert statement. How can I do this please help me.

Comment: [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/): _"Provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more Thenable objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events."_

Comment: @Andreas can you please answer it so I can understand what you saying.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait for the promises (deferreds) to be resolved

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more Thenable objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Signup', function() {
  console.log("Signup...");

  $.when(email_check('Signup'), mobile_check('Signup'))
    .done(function(){
      console.log("All done!")
    });
});

function email_check(Signup){
    var d = $.Deferred();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
     console.log("email_check resolved");
     d.resolve();
    }, 1000);
    
    return d;
}

function mobile_check(Signup){
    var d = $.Deferred();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
     console.log("mobile_check resolved");
     d.resolve();
    }, 2000);
    
    return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="Signup">Signup</button>
```